# JQuery - Show() then focus() does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, focus, show, tabindex

This  is the script

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
        
            $(this).removeClass("focus");
            var a = $(this).context.id;

            if (a.indexOf('guest') > 0)
            {
                if ($(this).val()&&$(this).val()!=0)
                    {
                        //$(this).parent().parent().next().show();      
                        var b = $(this).parent().parent().next().children().find("textarea");
                        b.parent().parent().show();
                        b.addClass("focus");
                        b.focus();
                    }
                    
                                    
                else
                    {
                        $(this).parent().parent().next().children().find("textarea").val('');
                        $(this).parent().parent().next().hide();}       
            }
        });
    
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML

> ```
> <table width="620" border="1">
>   <tr>
>      <td>&nbsp;</td>
>      <td style="width:40%"> Memebers $40 </td>
>      <td style="width:40%"> Each guest $45 </td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr>
>      <td><input name="breakfast1" type="checkbox" value="breakfast1" tabindex="0" /></td>
>      <td>September 12, 2012</td>
>      <td style="width:50%">How many guests
>         <input type="text" maxlength="2" size="3" id="1guest" name="1guest" tabindex="1" />
>      </td>
>   </tr>
>   <tr style="display:none">
>      <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
>      <td>
>         <textarea class="guests" style="width:300px;" id="1mguests" name="1mguests"  rows="4" tabindex="2">   </textarea>
>         <br /><span></span>
>      </td>
>   </tr>    </table>    and so on<br/>
> ```

What am I trying to accomplish:
When tabbing out of the 1guest text field check if the input field has something and if so, un hide (show) the next tr and set the focus to the textarea in the that tr.

What is the problem:
When one enters number of guests in the 1guest input field and TAB out of it, the hidden tr shows OK, the textarea input in the tr gets the class .focus BUT does not get the foucs. What Can be the issue? Is it because the TAB is applied after the focus and therefore goes to the next input field?
In any event can you propose a solution to what I am trying to accomplish?

Thanks

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/NBjqm/) on ff and chrome for me.

Comment: My testings were all in Chrome. I had many iterations. The one I posted in the question was a little different from my last iteration which had the focus comment out trying to see if the TAB will work. When I uncommmented it it does work. So is the suggested answer by Farser. BTW, testing your link works but have you noticed that the cursor does not show? Yes, if you type the keystorkes do go into the textarea. If you shift-tab and tab again the cursor shows OK. I wonder why? With Fraser answer the cursor shows OK. Maybe Fraser is right - timing issue. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure man? It's working perfectly fine with cursor and everything for me, well, glad you got it solved. `=]`

Comment: Using chrome, I just tried your sample on jsfiddle (which I just learned about thanks to you) and the cursor was not blinking in the empty textarea. The textarea does get the border indicating that it has the focus. I then added another a regular (not hidden) textarea after the table and when I tab into it, still the cursor does not show. I guess it is an issue with browser then. Any way, thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that the .show() is executing in turn, but finishing after the addClass() and focus()

Try this:

```
b.parent().parent().show(function(){
     b.addClass("focus");
     b.focus();
});
```